# Render an SSRS report running 'integrated' with Sharepoint2010 to a separate Sharepoint2007 doc library

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

Current Production Environment:

> MOSS 2007
>
> SQL Server 2008 Reporting Server running in Sharepoint integrated mode

Current Staging Environment:

> Sharepoint 2010
>
> SQL Server 2008R2 Reporting Server (Sharepoint integrated mode)

I would like to render (Excel) via a subscription a report from the Staging server to a document library on the current production MOSS 2007 server.  The main reason is to utilise some of the new features (spark lines, named Excel sheets) immediately.

The full migration from 2007->2010 is going to take some time and is in several phases which the business cannot wait for.

The current SSRS2008 server I guess is irrelevant.  Upgrading the report part on the existing environment is unfortunately not an option.  Rendering to an email and that email being the destination document library is a consideration but I am worried I may lose the additional metadata (columns) on the destination XLS.  It is currently setup to overwrite and store history.

Answer (score 0):

Can you render the report on the staging server to a file share, and rather than a UNC path, provide the URL for the production document library?